# PL/SQL update based on flag

Tags: plsql

I have a table "flags" containing flags with "name" and "value" where "name" is the name of the flag and "value" is either 'T' or 'F'

I would like to update a table based on a flag with name 'enable_feature' in the following manner:

```
BEGIN;
IF ((SELECT flags.value FROM flags WHERE flags.name = 'enable_feature') = 'T')
UPDATE... SET...;
ELSE
UPDATE... SET...;
END IF;
END;
```

My trouble seems to be in the IF statement. Specifically, i get the following error:

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the
>   following:
>
> ( - + case mod new not null          continue avg count current
>   exists max min prior sql stddev    sum variance execute forall merge
>   time timestamp interval    date       pipe

How do I modify this statement such that I can perform an UPDATE/SET statement based on the value of 'enable_feature' (The UPDATE/SET statement is on a different table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE
  v flags.value%type;
BEGIN
  SELECT flags.value into v FROM flags WHERE flags.name = 'enable_feature';
  IF v = 'T' THEN
    UPDATE... SET...;
  ELSE
    UPDATE... SET...;
  END IF;
END;
```